# Типы выражение преобразование на 0 php

Tags: php

сделал поиск по строке задал нужные количество строк и добавил в базу данных в столбце тип данных real но иногда в нужных количество строк добавляется не по типу. Как сделать если не по типу сделать 0.

```
echo $shtraf=substr($contents_file,$shtraf,4);
```

28171650.M04 TRFP 0003AASU 180428 9045 0 **;;;X** 2437922427

где ";;;X" должно быть 0

Answer (score 0):

использовав preg_replace все получилось

```
$shtraf=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $shtraf);
```